# IP restriction for IIS doesn't work properly

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with IIS restrictions for IP.
I have a VPN connection (only one NIC) and set a range of static IPs that are assigned to each user that is connecting. I set the same range on IIS server (both VPN server and IIS server are in the same subnet). When I try to open the site from outside the range, everything works correctly, but when I connect using VPN, the site can't be found. Even when I type the IP directly. It is a lab environment set on VPS machines

Comment: Is the range of IPs that is assigned to the VPN clients in another subnet? This could very well be a routing or firewall issue, but there is not enough information to tell.

Comment: I found a way around. It was problem with routing. Range is in the same subnet

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question, if you think that it may help others.